# Change datetime format with python(CSV)

Tags: python

I have this csv file which contains 2 columns: date of each day in 2021 and the related day of the week. the format of the date is dd/mm/yyyy, I need to write a program that requests a date in 2021 as input in the format of ‘mm/dd/yy’ and then gives its day of the week.

01/01/21,Friday
01/02/21,Saturday
01/03/21,Sunday
01/04/21,Monday
01/05/21,Tuesday
01/06/21,Wednesday
01/07/21,Thursday
01/08/21,Friday
01/09/21,Saturday

I tried datetime.datetime.strptime but it requires a string as the first item, I want to change the whole column.

Comment: Please, don't post images of data, code, etc. Copy/paste as text here. Also show your code [mre]. You need to iterate over rows and process each value OR use pandas and process whole column at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the input from the user as a str, then check if it is date in your code and then convert it to a date to check the year and return the day based on the entered year.
Something like the below code, assuming your dataframe name is df

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import is_datetime64_any_dtype
import os
from uuid import uuid4



entered_date= input("Enter a date in 2021 in the formate dd/mm/yy")

## check if it is a date 
isDate= is_datetime64_any_dtype(entered_date)

if isDate:
    date = pd.to_datetime(entered_date, format='%d-%m-%y', errors='coerce')
    
    year = date.date.today().year
    ## check the year 2021
    if year!=2021:
        "The entered date is not in 2021"
    else:
        print(df.loc[df['date'] == date]['Day'])
else:
    "The entered value is not a valid date"
```

Comment: thanks but my purpose is when user enter mm/dd/yyyy, the program will find the match date in csv(raw data in dd/mm/yyyy format), and return the day of the week of the mm/dd/yyyy input

Comment: just change the else to this format using loc: `df.loc[df['Col1'] == foo]['Col2']` , I edited my code above. let me know if this works. to read from CVS using pandas import the data into a dataframe using: `df = pd.read_csv(r'path/filename.csv') `. The code above assumes the columns names for date and day are 'date', 'Day' respectively.

Comment: Why do you need a csv to get the day of the week for a given date?